# Type declaration for number division

Tags: haskell, types, sicp

I tried all possible type declarations but I can't make this code even compile. The trick is in handling types for division. I tried `Num a`, `Fractional a`, `Float a` etc.

```
cube x = x * x * x

sum' term a next b =
    if a > b
    then 0
    else term a + sum' term (next a) next b

integral f a b n = (h / 3) * (sum' term 0 succ n)  where
    h = (b - a) / n
    y k = f $ a + (k * h)
    term k
        | k == 0 || k == n  = y k
        | odd  k            = 4 * y k
        | even k            = 2 * y k

main = do
    print $ integral cube 0 1 100      -- 0.25
    print $ (\x -> 3 * x * x) 1 3 100  -- 26
```

I isolated problem by deleting `(/)` function. This code compiles without any type declaration at all:

```
cube x = x * x * x

sum' term a next b =
    if a > b
    then 0
    else term a + sum' term (next a) next b

integral f a b n = (sum' term 0 succ n)  where
    h = (b - a)
    y k = f $ a + (k * h)
    term k
        | k == 0 || k == n  = y k
        | odd  k            = 4 * y k
        | even k            = 2 * y k

main = do
    print $ integral cube 0 1 100
```

Another question is how to debug cases like this? Haskell's error messages doesn't help much, it's kind of hard to understand something like `The type variable a0 is ambiguous` or `Could not deduce (a1 ~ a)`.

P. S. It's ex. 1.29 from SICP.

**Update**

Final answer is:

```
cube :: Num a => a -> a
cube x = x * x * x

sum' :: (Int -> Double) -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Double
sum' term a next b =
    if a > b
    then 0
    else term a + sum' term (next a) next b

integral :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Int -> Double
integral f a b n = (h / 3) * sum' term 0 (+1) n  where
    h = (b - a) / n'  where n' = fromIntegral n
    y k = f $ a + (k * h)
    term k
        | k == 0 || k == n  = y k'
        | odd  k            = 4 * y k'
        | even k            = 2 * y k'
        where k' = fromIntegral k

main = do
    print $ integral cube 0 1 100               -- 0.25
    print $ integral cube 0 1 1000              -- 0.25
    print $ integral (\x -> 3 * x * x) 1 3 100  -- 26
```

Comment: FYI it would be `Floating a` becuase `Float` is a concrete type

Comment: The first thing I do in cases like this is to write out the type of all top-level declarations. If I can't figure out the type, I ask `ghci` and then try to understand the result. If `ghci` doesn't accept the program, remove stuff until it does. This is a good habit in general, since it helps in understanding your program more precisely.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, it's gave me declarations like this:
`sum' :: (Num a1, Ord a) => (a -> a1) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a1`
`integral :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a -> a`

But it didn't help me :-(

Comment: @surganov, more practice with types would help you.  Most Haskellers eventually get to the point where they write the type before the function, and it helps them write the function.  GHCi `:t` is helpful, but no substitute for understanding.  Start [here in LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses)

Comment: Thanks, I've read this book already. So, this example is practice for me :-)

Comment: Side note: If I'm not very much mistaken, `succ` is from `Enum`, and may slow things down a tad (because it gives errors on overflow); don't use it if you don't need it. Since you're dealing with numbers, use `(+1)` instead.

Comment: Now I have this error: https://gist.github.com/surganov/d727fd50a18ccc867de8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/` is only used for types that are instances of `Fractional`, for `Integral` types use `quot`. You can use `quot` as an infix operator using backticks:

```
h = (b - a) `quot` n
```

The types of the two are

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
quot :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

There are no types that are instances of both `Fractional` and `Integral`, which is why none of the type signatures would work. Unfortunately GHC doesn't know that it's impossible for a type to be an instance of both classes, so the error messages are not very intuitive. You get used to the style of GHC error messages though, and the detail they give helps a lot.

Also, as was suggested in the comments, I completely agree that *all* top level definitions should be given type signatures (including `main`). It makes error messages *a lot* easier to read.

Edit: Based on the comments below, it looks like what you want is something more like this (type signature-wise)

```
cube :: Num a => a -> a

sum' :: (Int -> Double) -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Double

integral :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Int -> Double
```

You will need to use `fromIntegral` to convert from `Int` to `Double` in `h` and in `k`. The type errors should be at least a bit more readable with these type signatures though.

Comment: According to official docs, `quot` is integer division truncated toward zero, i. e. `5 quot 2 == 2` which unacceptable for numerically calculating integrals

Comment: @surganov The monomorphism restriction might be getting you because you don't have type declarations. Try using `(/)` and add type signatures to all the top level definitions and specify all the variables as being `Float`.

Comment: That's the problem I can't solve by myself — add the necessary type declarations to make this code run. Can you help me?

Comment: @surganov Well, I'm on my phone right now so I can't help too extensively. If no one else has answered when I get to a computer I can help some more. Try this though: use the type signature `integral :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float` and `sum' :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float` and likewise for `cube`

Comment: `No instance for (Integral Float) arising from a use of 'odd'. Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Float). In the expression: odd k`

Comment: @surganov If you want to round up for `even` and `odd`, using `ceiling`. Use `floor` if you want to round down.

Comment: What you probably want is to use `fromIntegral` to convert `Int` to floating point before dividing. Use `Double`, not `Float`, unless you have a good reason. Be sure to constrain your integral type with `::Int`; using `Integer` is the default, but not what you want (unless your integers are monstrously huge).

Comment: @surganov Yeah, I was mistaken. dfeuer is right, `fromIntegral` is what you need here. I edited my answer with some info that might help.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't make it work. Can you provide an exact listing?

Comment: @surganov I just noticed a problem with my `cube` signature, it's fixed now. If you use the code in your first example (without the very last line, which doesn't type check either way) along with the type signatures I've provided, the type checker will tell you what to do: whenever it says something like `Couldn't match expected type Double with Int`, you need to use `fromIntegral` to convert the `Int` to `Double`. It will say which variable to do apply it to.

Comment: It is important to learn to use the type checker in this way. It's one of the most important and powerful tools for the Haskell programmer. It takes practice, but it is becomes extremely useful. This also demonstrates the importance of type signatures for top-level definitions.

Comment: In this particular example, specialized to the types we're working with here, you can treat `fromIntegral` as though it has the type `Int -> Double`.